# Gutter horizontally not working with Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to put gutter (using Bootstrap v5) between the cols but somehow it is working horizontally, vertically it does.

```
<div class="right-section w-100 h-auto  container-fluid p-4">
  <div class="container summary">
    <h6 class="text-uppercase border-bottom border-1 fw-bold border-secondary pb-2 text-primary fs-6">Summary</h6>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row gx-2 bg-danger p-4">
        <div class="col d-flex  rounded bg-light align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h5 class="h-full p-4 text-uppercase fs-6 text-white">Completed</h5>
          <span class="bg-warning p-4 rounded-end">06</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex  rounded  bg-light align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h5 class="h-full  p-4 text-uppercase fs-6 text-white">Pending</h5>
          <span class="bg-warning p-4 rounded-end">03</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex  rounded  bg-light align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h5 class="h-full  p-4 text-uppercase fs-6 text-white">Scheduled</h5>
          <span class="bg-warning p-4 rounded-end">03</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col d-flex  rounded  bg-light align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h5 class="h-full  p-4 text-uppercase fs-6 text-white">Postponed</h5>
          <span class="bg-warning p-4 rounded-end">03</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working.. please clarify the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap gutter class gx-5 isn't working horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159026/bootstrap-gutter-class-gx-5-isnt-working-horizontally)

Answer (score 2):

Just add the div tag after the "col" class div.

Change this:

```
<div class="col d-flex  rounded bg-light align-items-center justify-content- between">
  <h5 class="h-full p-4 text-uppercase fs-6 text-white">Completed</h5>
  <span class="bg-warning p-4 rounded-end">06</span>
</div>
```

with:

```
<div class="col">
  <div class="d-flex rounded bg-light align-items-center justify-content-between">
     <h5 class="h-full p-4 text-uppercase fs-6 text-white">Completed</h5>
     <span class="bg-warning p-4 rounded-end">06</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Gutters will set padding-right and padding-left on each column. So because of that, you should not add anything in the "col" div then only the padding will be visible.